# Find the area of a figure in a triangle

Tags: triangles, area

Triangle $ABC$ in the figure has area $10$ . Points $D,E,$ and $F$, all distinct from $A,B,$ and $C$, are on sides $AB,BC,$ and $CA$ respectively, and $AD=2$ , $DB=3$ .
If triangle $ABE$ and quadrilateral $DBEF$ have equal areas,then what is that area?
[image]

**Efforts made:** I've tried to add some extra lines to see if i could get something usefull but ,guess, i didnt get anything . It seems like the problem is asking  some crazy creative thing to be done,i cant see what.

Comment: I would begin my seting up the system of equations from your given constraints. You know that the area of the large triangle is 10 so 10=5/2*h, and that the area of ABE can be set equal to the area of DBEF. How many more equations can you introduce to match the number of unknowns?

Comment: I've tried to decompose the area of the quadrilateral in question but there are so many variables and that quadrilateral is really an ugly one.

Comment: $DF$ and $AE$ intersect at $G$. The equal area requirement can be translated to $\triangle ADG$ and $\triangle EFG$ having equal area.

Comment: Hint: $DE$ is parallel to $???$

Comment: @ Arthur can you please elaborate a little bit more ?

Comment: @Achille hui how can i prove that $DE$ is parallel to $AC$.i cant see how to do that.

Comment: $$\verb/Area/(\triangle ADE) = \verb/Area/(\triangle FDE) \implies
\verb/height/(A,DE) = \verb/height/(F,DE) \implies ...$$

Comment: Here's a small elaboration: The two figures you're told have equal area are each divided into two by the lines in the diagram. We have that the area of triangle $ABE$ becomes the area of $ADG +$ area of quadrilateral $DBEG$. Similarily, the area of quadrilateral $DBEF$ is equal to the area of triangle $EFG +$ area of quadrilateral $DBEG$. These two areas are assumed equal, and you can subtract the area of quadrilateral $DBEG$ from both of them and still have two areas that are equal.

Answer (score 1):

$[DBEF]=[ABE]$ is equivalent, by subtracting $[DBE]$ to both sides, to $[DEF]=[DEA]$.
These triangles share the $DE$-side, hence $[DEF]=[DEA]$ implies $DE\parallel AF$, so:
$$ \frac{BE}{BC}=\frac{BD}{BA}=\frac{3}{5} $$
and the area of $[BDE]$, consequently, equals $\frac{9}{25}[ABC]=\frac{18}{5}$. Since $[ABE]=\frac{5}{3}[DBE]$,
$$ [ABE]=[DBEF]=\color{red}{6} $$
follows.

Comment: Ho fatto stupidi errori di calcolo se no avrei ottenuto anch'io $6$. Comunque grazie mille per la risposta(p.s: scusa se non c'entra con la domanda,ma hai studiato alla normale di Pisa ?)

Comment: @Jhon: you're welcome. By the way, yes, I studied there, but just the first year of my student career.